# Question about address operations in neon intrinstics

Tags: arm, neon

I'm rearranging an array in my project on ARMv7. Now I get the elements' address d[] in the order I expect. To make the code more efficient, I want to use neon intrinstics in C++. Now my problem is, I can load the address array d[] by using `vld1q_s32()`, but I do not know how to read the elements of this vector as addresses.The instructions I know can only simply duplicate one vector.

This problem has been confusing me for several days. Or neon cannot do certain thing?

Thanks for your answering.

---

Here is my code:

---

```
void InputRearrange(int8_t* din, int8_t* dout, const int x, const int y){
    int8_t* dout_array[16];
    int out = 0;
    dout_array[0] = din;
    for(int n = 1; n < 16; n++) {//get the address of the first line in z-axis
        dout_array[n] = dout_array[n - 1] + x*y; 
    }
        for(int y_count = 0; y_count < y; y_count++) {
            for(int x_count = 0; x_count < x; x_count++) {
                for(int z_count = 0; z_count < 16; z_count++) {
                    dout[out++] = *(dout_array[k]++);//dout_array[k]++ let dout_array[k] moves in x-axis and I want to change this loop into neon intrinsics.   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

din[ ] is the original array and is like a 3-D array as a cube but stored as a 1-D one. The cube has three axis: x, y , z(=16). The original way array din[ ] stores the elements from x-axis first and then y-axis and last z-axis. But my code changed the order to z-axis first and then x-axis and last y-axis. I would like to use neon intrinsics in the final for loop， but it seems that it cannot be realized.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want.  Can you give equivalent C++ code or pseudocode?

Comment: It sounds kind of like you want a gather instruction, which would treat each element of a vector as an address and load from each of them, but Neon doesn't have one.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do.  Maybe my method is a wrong because my instructor told us that it can be realized by neon intrinsics.

Comment: I‘ve post my code. Would you please have a look at it? THX. @NateEldredge

Comment: No, it's not possible as long as x and y are variable values.

Answer (score 1):

Your code rearranges a three-dimensional array `int8_t (&output)[y][x][16]` to `int8_t (&input)[16][y][x]`, which is also equivalent to transposing a 2d array of `int8_t (&out)[x*y][16]` to `int8_t (&in)[16][x*y]`.

This can definitely benefit from arm neon intrinsics that can interleave/deinterleave either registers (vzip,vuzp) or memory content (vldN, vstN).

```
// planarizes next 128 bytes to 16 planes
void planarize(int8_t *in, int8_t *out, int xy) {
    int8_t * o_1 = out + 4*xy;
    int8_t * o_2 = out + 8*xy;
    int8_t * o_3 = out + 12*xy;

    int8x16x4_t a = vld4q_s8(in); in+=64;
    int8x16x4_t b = vld4q_s8(in); in+=64;
    int8x16x2_t c = vuzpq_s8(a.val[0], b.val[0]);
    int8x16x2_t d = vuzpq_s8(a.val[1], b.val[1]);
    int8x16x2_t e = vuzpq_s8(a.val[2], b.val[2]);
    int8x16x2_t f = vuzpq_s8(a.val[3], b.val[3]);
    c = vuzpq_s8(c.val[0], c.val[1]);
    d = vuzpq_s8(d.val[0], d.val[1]);
    e = vuzpq_s8(e.val[0], e.val[1]);
    f = vuzpq_s8(f.val[0], f.val[1]);
    // now c = 0 16 32 48 64 80  96 112  4 20 36 52 68 84 100 116
    //         8 24 40 56 72 88 104 120 12 28 44 60 76 92 108 124
    // d = c + 1, e = d + 1, f = e + 1
    vst1_s8(out + 0 * xy, vget_low_s8(c.val[0]);
    vst1_s8(out + 1 * xy, vget_low_s8(d.val[0]);
    vst1_s8(out + 2 * xy, vget_low_s8(e.val[0]);
    vst1_s8(out + 3 * xy, vget_low_s8(f.val[0]);

    vst1_s8(o_1 + 4 * xy, vget_high_s8(c.val[0]);
    vst1_s8(o_1 + 5 * xy, vget_high_s8(d.val[0]);
    vst1_s8(o_1 + 6 * xy, vget_high_s8(e.val[0]);
    vst1_s8(o_1 + 7 * xy, vget_high_s8(f.val[0]);

    vst1_s8(o_2 + 0 * xy, vget_low_s8(c.val[1]);
    vst1_s8(o_2 + 1 * xy, vget_low_s8(d.val[1]);
    vst1_s8(o_2 + 2 * xy, vget_low_s8(e.val[1]);
    vst1_s8(o_2 + 3 * xy, vget_low_s8(f.val[1]);

    vst1_s8(o_3 + 4 * xy, vget_high_s8(c.val[1]);
    vst1_s8(o_3 + 5 * xy, vget_high_s8(d.val[1]);
    vst1_s8(o_3 + 6 * xy, vget_high_s8(e.val[1]);
    vst1_s8(o_3 + 7 * xy, vget_high_s8(f.val[1]);
}
```

The opposite would interleave from 16 independent planes

```
 int8x16x2_t load4(int8_t *in, int xy) {
     int8x8_t a0 = vld1_s8(in);
     int8x8_t a1 = vld1_s8(in + xy);
     int8x8_t a2 = vld1_s8(in + 2 * xy);
     int8x8_t a3 = vld1_s8(in + 3 * xy);
     auto a = vzipq_s8(vcombine_s8(a0, a0), vcombine_s8(a1, a1)).val[0];
     auto b = vzipq_s8(vcombine_s8(a2, a2), vcombine_s8(a3, a3)).val[0];
     return vzipq_s8(a,b);
 }

 int8_t *store4(int8x16x2_t a, int8x16x2_t b, int8x16x2_t c, int8x16x2_t d, int8_t *out) {
     int32x4x4_t A{
         vreinterpretq_s32_s8(a.val[0]), 
         vreinterpretq_s32_s8(b.val[0]), 
         vreinterpretq_s32_s8(c.val[0]), 
         vreinterpretq_s32_s8(d.val[0])};

     int32x4x4_t B{
         vreinterpretq_s32_s8(a.val[1]), 
         vreinterpretq_s32_s8(b.val[1]), 
         vreinterpretq_s32_s8(c.val[1]), 
         vreinterpretq_s32_s8(d.val[1])};
     vst4q_s32((int32_t*)out, A); out += 64;         
     vst4q_s32((int32_t*)out, B); out += 64;
     return out;
 }

 void interleave(int8_t *in, int8_t *out, int xy) {
     int w = xy;
     while (w >= 8) {
       auto a = load4(in, xy);
       auto b = load4(in + 4*xy, xy);
       auto c = load4(in + 8*xy, xy);
       auto d = load4(in + 12*xy, xy);
       in += 8;
       out = store4(a,b,c,d, out);
       w -= 8;
     }
 }
```

Handling the excess `(xy & 7 != 0)` can be done by processing one full block aligned at `in_ptr + xy - 8` and `out_ptr + xy * 16 - 8*16`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will have a look at it later. Feel sorry for not replying to you on time cuz I do not use stackoverflow very often.

Comment: It seems that armv7 does not contain the vzip1q_s8 function. The vzip functions in v7 only have vzip(q)_s(or u/p/f)8(or 16/32). Can I use these functions instead? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, on armv7 `uzp1_xx()` is implemented as `uzp_xx().val[0]`.